# Finding equilibrium and bifurcation points for first order ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the equilibrium and bifurcation points for $$\frac{d}{dx}=rx+xe^{-x}.$$ I started by noticing that $x=0$ is an equilibrium point for all $r$. Also, I then set the RHS equal to zero and solved for $x$. I found that $x=-\ln(-r)$ so this means that $r=-1$ also creates an equilibrium point. I'm not exactly sure where to take this problem further to solve for the bifurcation points. I know that I need to create a bifurcation diagram, and I think that I need to sketch a graph with $x$ in the vertical axis and $r$ as the independent variable. Is $x=-\ln(-r)$ what I want to sketch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The system has trivial equilibrium point $x_0=0$ and interior equilibrium point $x^*=-\ln(-r)$ provided $r<0$. So for positive values  of $r$, the interior equilibrium point does not exist.

Also you can draw the bifurcation diagram in $x-r$ plane as you mentioned, what type of bifurcation the system exhibit. An easy method for checking what type of bifurcation the system exhibit is to use [MATCONT](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/MATCONT) software which is based on MATLAB package.
[image]
The eigenvalue of the Jacobian matrix calculated at the equilibrium point $x_0$ and $x^*$, of the system are $r-1$ and $r\ln(-r)$. So $x_0$ is locally stable for $r<-1$ and $x^*$ is locally stable for $r<0$, which is also existence condition for  $x^*$. So the stability of $x_0$ changes at $r=-1$. Therefore $r=-1$ is the bifurcation point. In the above figure the point $r=-1$ is shown as a branch point.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I'm trying to work with the MATCONT software and there's a learning curve associated with it.

Comment: How did you get the point of the BP shown on the plot?

Comment: @Peetrius, Using MATCONT software.

Comment: I understand that, I have the plot. Where in MATCONT did you get the coordinate to show on the graph?

Comment: When you plot the bifurcation diagram in $x-r$ plane, MATCONT by default shows the coordinate on the graph.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't get that for my plot, or for my other plots.

Comment: Then you manually add the axes on the plot by editing the MATLAB figure through   axis properties.